# Staging Area Structure

Tags: data-warehouse

I wonder what is the official design structure of the Staging Area?
if we have the operational database and we land it into Landing Area with same data and structure then into staging for cleansing and processing...
in that stage will the data applied with the ETL to transform them into FACT and DIM and then run cleansing and processing then just copy it into DWH.. or we run cleansing and processing into structure shape similar to the operational shape after that we run the ETL on the output of staging to shape the FACTs and DIM and load it into DWH..

Short Question: are the FACTs and DIM created inside staging before processing or after processing using the ETL to the DWH?

Comment: There is no “official design structure” - unless you are following a particular methodology and even then most of them are descriptive not prescriptive. In general, the different layers have different purposes and so contain different data structures; so no, you wouldn’t create facts and dims in two different layers